# Accessing data in service from page ionic

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, mobile

I am trying to get data from an API and I want to display it in a page. But I can't seem to reach the data outside of the 'subscribe' function. I want to know what is the easiest way to reach the data provided by the Provider/Service. I know I can just put the function in my HomePage.ts but it is super ugly way of coding. None of the similar looking answers provided a solid solution for my problem.

**prayer-data.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';;
import { Times } from '../../app/times';

@Injectable()
export class PrayerDataProvider {

  tijdenLijst: any[];
  vandaag: Date = new Date();

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() : void {
    //console.log(this._data);
    this.http.get("http://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city=Amsterdam&country=" +
    "The%20Netherlands&method=1&school=1&month=9&year=2018")
    .subscribe(data => {
      //works
      this.tijdenLijst = data.data[0].timings;
      console.log(this.tijdenLijst);
    });
    //undefined
    console.log(this.tijdenLijst);
  }


}
```

**HomePage.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { PrayerDataProvider } from '../../providers/prayer-data/prayer-data';
import { Times } from '../../app/times';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {

  tijdenVandaag: Times[];
  tijden: Times;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private provider: PrayerDataProvider) {
  }

  getTimes(): void {  
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }

}
```

How do I call the data here (in HomePage.ts)? I have tried dozens of ways. But can't seem to get it working. I tried observables too. But I seemingly don't know how to work with those properly. Nice solutions will be appreciated VERY much. Also in solutions could you provide specific instructions. I am coding with this framework since 2 days so I am not very experienced. Have mercy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume "Times" is your DTO which describes the data returned by your API.

In this case i would change loadData in your provider to look like this:

```
loadData() : Observable<Times[]> {
    return this.http.get<Times[]>("http://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city=Amsterdam&country=" +
    "The%20Netherlands&method=1&school=1&month=9&year=2018");
  }
```

In ionViewDidLoad() you can then call this function and save the output in your class variable "tijdenVandaag" to make it accessible in your component like this:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
 this.provider.loadData().subscribe( r => this.tijdenVandaag = r, e => console.error(e));
}
```

In the HTML template home.html you can then go on and visualize the data the way you want.

Just make sure you handle the initial case, when the value is null until it's loaded. So maybe wrap it with a *ngIf like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="tijdenVandaag != null">
    <div *ngFor="let t of tijdenVandaag>{{t.id}}</div>
</ng-container>
```